# Found the answer myself for one of my questions - how to award bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, self-answer

Yesterday I started a bounty for a question I posted on Stack Overflow. I received a couple of answers, none of them solved my problem, but one of them gave suggestions that pushed me in the right direction, leading me to eventually find the answer myself.

I posted the answer myself to my question (in case it would be relevant to others), but what should I do with the bounty? I understand I cannot give it to myself, would it be best to give it to the user who provided the suggestion that helped me find the answer, even though they didn't actually provide the correct answer? Or should I just leave the bounty, and not award it to anyone?

Comment: Award the bounty to the most helpful answer, but mark your own solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better @Mikk3lRo

Comment: There's a lot of info about bounties, here: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're free to do whichever you want.  If you feel that one of the other answers has earned the bounty, you're certainly welcome to award it to them, even if you had to build on what they posted.  If you feel that their contributions were insufficient to merit the bounty, it's entirely appropriate for you to not award it.  Though it might end up being automatically awarded for half the amount to one of the answers, if there is one that meets the criteria.